# 4 Memory Sticks on Dual Channel

Tags: memory, dual-channel

I have an Asrock fatal1ty z170 gaming k6 motherboard, which has 4 memory slots but only supports dual channel, so from what I read if I use all four it won't run in quad-channel, but dual-channel between 1-3 2-4 slots.

In a common scenario of running 2 memory sticks in dual channel, if the sticks are not the same model they will run on the lowest common denominator, so if one is 3000Mhz and the other 3200Mhz they will run dual channel at 3000Mhz. My question is if that rule applies between all 4 sticks if they run in dual channel pairs, so if I have a pair at 3000Mhz and another at 3200Mhz, will they run at their speed or will the second pair slow to 3000Mhz?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after exploring more around some tech forums and discussing this with my local shop tech team the answer is, in case someone has the same doubt:

They will run at 3000Mhz. The ram will always work on the lowest common denominator across all ram slots, not only their "channel partner". So its ideal they are all the same frequency and CL (about CL i don't know exactly if this is recommendation or mandatory, as soon as i found that out, I'll update the post :) )